# CSS MegaMenu hovering shows nested content

Tags: css, html, menu, navigation, hover

I've been trying to build a mega nav and I can't figure out how to target an anchor and have its dropdown content to automatically display. I have an example of my work on codepen at http://codepen.io/shanekweb/pen/EZpjKo

So as an example, if I hover over the first link News and some more links show up, I need the content that pops out to the right for "one" to show up automatically when the main item News is hovered over.

I need this so that a customer immediately see's content for all of the first sub links when the main items are hovered over.

```
    <div class="droppable">
        <a class="firstLink" href="#">News</a>
        <div class="megaNav">
            <div class="drop1st">
                <div class="parentMenu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><strong>first heading</strong></li>
                        <li class="expand">
                            <a href="#">one</a>
                            <div class="rightContent">
                                <section class="rightContent1">
                                    <h4>Title 1</h4>
                                </section><!--rightContent1-->
                                <section class="rightContent2">
                                    <h4>Title 2</h4>
                                </section><!--rightContent2-->
                                <section class="rightContent2">
                                    <h4>Title 3</h4>
                                </section><!--rightContent3-->
                            </div><!--rightContent-->
                        </li>
                        <li class="expand">
                            <a href="#">two</a>
                            <div class="rightContent">
                                <section class="rightContent1">
                                    <h4>Title 4</h4>
                                </section><!--rightContent1-->
                                <section class="rightContent2">
                                    <h4>Title 5</h4>
                                </section><!--rightContent2-->
                                <section class="rightContent2">
                                    <h4>Title 6</h4>
                                </section><!--rightContent3-->
                            </div><!--rightContent-->
                        </li>
                        <li class="expand">
                            <a href="#">three</a>
                            <div class="rightContent">
                                <section class="rightContent1">
                                    <h4>Title 7</h4>
                                </section><!--rightContent1-->
                                <section class="rightContent2">
                                    <h4>Title 8</h4>
                                </section><!--rightContent2-->
                                <section class="rightContent2">
                                    <h4>Title 9</h4>
                                </section><!--rightContent3-->
                            </div><!--rightContent-->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--megaNav-->
    </div><!--droppable-->


    <div class="droppable">
        <a class="firstLink" href="#">top brands &amp; agencies</a>
        <div class="megaNav">
            <div class="drop1st">
                <div class="parentMenu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><strong>second heading</strong></li>
                        <li class="expand">
                            <a href="#">one</a>
                            <div class="rightContent">
                                <section class="rightContent1">
                                    <h4>Title 1</h4>
                                </section><!--rightContent1-->
                                <section class="rightContent2">
                                    <h4>Title 2</h4>
                                </section><!--rightContent2-->
                                <section class="rightContent2">
                                    <h4>Title 3</h4>
                                </section><!--rightContent3-->
                            </div><!--rightContent-->
                        </li>
                        <li class="expand">
                            <a href="#">two</a>
                            <div class="rightContent">
                                <section class="rightContent1">
                                    <h4>Title 4</h4>
                                </section><!--rightContent1-->
                                <section class="rightContent2">
                                    <h4>Title 5</h4>
                                </section><!--rightContent2-->
                                <section class="rightContent2">
                                    <h4>Title 6</h4>
                                </section><!--rightContent3-->
                            </div><!--rightContent-->
                        </li>
                        <li class="expand">
                            <a href="#">three</a>
                            <div class="rightContent">
                                <section class="rightContent1">
                                    <h4>Title 7</h4>
                                </section><!--rightContent1-->
                                <section class="rightContent2">
                                    <h4>Title 8</h4>
                                </section><!--rightContent2-->
                                <section class="rightContent2">
                                    <h4>Title 9</h4>
                                </section><!--rightContent3-->
                            </div><!--rightContent-->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--megaNav-->
    </div><!--droppable-->

</nav><!--mainNav-->



#mainNav {
margin: auto;
max-width: 1242px;
position: relative;
box-sizing: border-box;

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.droppable {
    float: left;

    a.firstLink:hover > .megaNav > .parentMenu > li.expand:first-child {
        > .rightContent {
            display: block;
        }
    }

    > a {
        padding: 5px 15px;
    }

    .megaNav {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;

        .drop1st {
            overflow: auto;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
            background: #fff;
            min-height: 380px;
            background: #efefef;

            .parentMenu {
                width: 16%;
                min-height: 380px;
                background: #fafafa;

                ul {
                    margin-left: 0;
                    list-style: none;
                    padding-left: 0;
                }

                li.expand:hover > div {
                    display: block;
                }

                .rightContent {
                    display: none;
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 16%;
                    top: 0;
                    width: 84%;
                    min-height: 380px;

                    h4 {
                        margin: 0;
                    }

                    .rightContent1 {
                        width: 25%;
                        float: left;
                    }

                    .rightContent2 {
                        width: 25%;
                        float: left;
                    }

                    .rightContent3 {
                        width: 50%;
                        float: left;
                    }
                }

                ul {
                    margin: 0;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    &:hover {
        .megaNav {
            display: block;
        }
    }
}
}
```

What I was trying in the css was something like this but I can't get it to work

```
a.firstLink:hover > .megaNav > .parentMenu > li.expand:first-child {
    > .rightContent {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) (`+`) to select the `.megaNav` that follows the `.firstLink`, and after that use simple nesting – i.e., `.classone .classtwo` – instead of using the `>` selector, which is overly specific in some cases where you had it. (For example, the parent of `.parentMenu` is `.drop1st`, not `.megaNav`, so `.megaNav > .parentMenu` won’t select anything.)

You’ll also have to use `!important` to override other styles of `display: none`.

The result would be:

```
.firstLink + .megaNav .parentMenu li.expand:nth-of-type(2) .rightContent {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Heads up, though, that’s gonna require a lot of variations of that rule to make everything show up correctly because you’ll have to be toggling `display: none` and `display: block` with `!important` every time, making for a lot of CSS. If possible, you may try to simplify the markup a bit and make your CSS rules less specific so that you can get away without using `!important`.